# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o : Simple JSON parser not working

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone see what is wrong with this simple JSON parser? 
([JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/m36n6zoj/1/))

I am getting an error in the console saying 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');

var json = {
            type: "cow",
            sound: "moo",
            colors: ["black", "white", "brown"],
            feed: {
                types: ["hay", "grass"],
                consistency: "wet"
            }
        };

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

//called with every property and it's value
function process(key,value) {
   console.log(key + " : " + value);
}

function traverse(o,func) {
    for (var i in o) {
        func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            //going on step down in the object tree!!
            traverse(o[i],func);
        }
    }
}

//that's all... no magic, no bloated framework
traverse(json,process);
```

Comment: Why are you parsing an object? You should be parsing a string! Your data is already parsed!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any parsing whatsoever! Your data is already in a *JavaScript object*, not a *JSON string*.

This is often a confusion - JSON is a string, which *represents* data. JavaScript objects are the actual data stored by JS.

Comment: So how would I get the value for `type`?

Comment: @Imray: It's an object. `type` is a property of the object. So: `json.type`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` isn't JSON, it's a reference to an object that was defined by the object initialiser on the right-hand side of that `=`. No JSON in sight. JSON is a *textual*, non-source-code notation for data exchange. There's no reason to parse what you have; the JavaScript engine *already* parsed it: http://jsfiddle.net/m36n6zoj/2/

The *reason* you get the error you get is that `JSON.parse` coerces its first argument to a string (since it's for parsing JSON, which is textual, and so held in strings in JavaScript code). If you take a generic object like the one your `json` refers to and turn it into a string, you get `"[object Object]"`. So you're doing this:

```
JSON.parse("[object Object]")
```

To a JSON parser, that looks like the beginning of an array (`[`) followed by the letter `o`. The letter `o` is invalid in that position in JSON, and so you get the error.

Of course, if you really want to use JSON (perhaps you're normally going to load `json` via ajax or something and this is just test code), you can: http://jsfiddle.net/m36n6zoj/3/

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');

var json =
    '{' +
    '    "type": "cow",' +
    '    "sound": "moo",' +
    '    "colors": ["black", "white", "brown"],' +
    '    "feed": {' +
    '       "types": ["hay", "grass"],' +
    '       "consistency": "wet"' +
    '   }' +
    '}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

//called with every property and it's value
function process(key,value) {
   console.log(key + " : " + value);
}

function traverse(o,func) {
    for (var i in o) {
        func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
            //going on step down in the object tree!!
            traverse(o[i],func);
        }
    }
}

//that's all... no magic, no bloated framework
traverse(parsed,process);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have wrong json format , you need to add keys in double quotes like this

```
        "type": "cow"
```

this isnt a json object, it is a javascript object that you are providing so it wont be parsed, dou you want it to be JSON instead, go for stringify function than